# http outbound gateway not converting french characters

Tags: spring-integration

I have my spring integration http outbound gateway something like this.I am using my own rest template for pooling connection with ssl.I was getting 500 with french character hence I am injecting both UTF-8 and supported media type to  message converter.Now  Before I was injecting my own request factory and default rest template After injecting both then it started accepting french characters.Now  when i changed to use my own rest template it don't accept message converter and when i try to inject this to my rest template I get this exception

```
Cause is - Could not write request: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for request type [java.lang.String] and content type [text/plain;charset=UTF-8]
```

This worked for all request

```
<int-http:outbound-gateway id='batch-http'  header-mapper="headerMapper"
                           request-channel='toHttp'
                            request-factory="requestFactory"
                             message-converters="batchHTTPConverter"
                             url-expression="payload.contains('${filterAttribute}') ? '${url1}' : '${url2}'"  http-method="${httpMethod}"
                           expected-response-type='java.lang.String' charset='${charset}'
                           reply-timeout='${replyTimeout}' reply-channel='output'>
</int-http:outbound-gateway>

 <beans:bean  id="batchHTTPConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter">
    <beans:constructor-arg index="0"  value="UTF-8"/>
    <beans:property name="supportedMediaTypes" value = "application/json;UTF-8" />

</beans:bean>


<beans:bean id="requestFactory" class="test.batch.httpclient.CustomClientHttpRequestFactory">       
 <beans:constructor-arg ref="verifier"/>
  </beans:bean>

 <beans:bean id="verifier"
      class="batch.NullHostnameVerifier">

</beans:bean>
```

This is not working for french or any input request

```
    <header-filter input-channel="input"
                   output-channel="inputX" header-names="x-death"/>

    <service-activator input-channel="inputX" ref="gw" />

    <gateway id="gw" default-request-channel="toHttp" default-reply-timeout="0"  error-channel="errors" />

    <beans:bean id="inputfields" class="testbatch.httpclient.HTTPInputProperties">
        <beans:property name="nonRetryErrorCodes" value="${nonRetryErrorCodes}"/>
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="responseInterceptor" class="testbatch.httpclient.ResponseInterceptor">
        <beans:property name="inputProperties" ref="inputfields" />
    </beans:bean>

    <chain input-channel="errors" output-channel="output">
        <!-- examine payload.cause (http status code etc) and decide whether
             to throw an exception or return the status code for sending to output -->
        <header-filter header-names="replyChannel, errorChannel" />
        <transformer ref="responseInterceptor"  />
    </chain>


    <int-http:outbound-gateway id='batch-http'  header-mapper="headerMapper"
                               request-channel='toHttp'
                               rest-template="batchRestTemplate"
                               url-expression="payload.contains('${filterAttribute}') ? '${url1}' : '${url2}'"  http-method="${httpMethod}"
                               expected-response-type='java.lang.String' charset='${charset}'
                               reply-timeout='${replyTimeout}' reply-channel='output'>
    </int-http:outbound-gateway>

    <beans:bean  id="batchHTTPConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter" >
        <beans:constructor-arg index="0"  value="UTF-8"/>
        <beans:property name="supportedMediaTypes" value = "application/json;UTF-8" />

    </beans:bean>




     <beans:bean  id="batchRestTemplate" class="testbatch.httpclient.BatchRestTemplate" >
        <beans:property name="batchHTTPConverter" ref="batchHTTPConverter"/>



</beans:bean>



<beans:bean id="requestFactory"
            class="testbatch.httpclient.CustomClientHttpRequestFactory">

<beans:constructor-arg ref="verifier"/>

</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="verifier"
            class="testbatch.httpclient.NullHostnameVerifier">

</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="headerMapper" class="org.springframework.integration.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper"
            factory-method="outboundMapper">
<beans:property name="outboundHeaderNames" value="${mapHeaders}"/>
<beans:property name="userDefinedHeaderPrefix" value=""/>
</beans:bean>

<channel id="output" />
<channel id="input" />
<channel id="inputX" />
<channel id="toHttp" />

        </beans:beans>
```

My rest template

```
public class BatchRestTemplate  extends RestTemplate{

     private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory
                .getLogger(BatchRestTemplate.class);
     private StringHttpMessageConverter batchHTTPConverter;



    public StringHttpMessageConverter getBatchHTTPConverter() {
        return batchHTTPConverter;
    }

    public void setBatchHTTPConverter(StringHttpMessageConverter batchHTTPConverter) {
        this.batchHTTPConverter = batchHTTPConverter;
    }

    public BatchRestTemplate()  {
          super(createBatchHttpRequestFactory());

        List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters= new ArrayList<HttpMessageConverter<?>>();
        messageConverters.addAll(getMessageConverters());
        messageConverters.add(getBatchHTTPConverter());
        super.setMessageConverters(messageConverters);

    }

    private static ClientHttpRequestFactory createBatchHttpRequestFactory()  {

            CloseableHttpClient httpClient;
            HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory httpRequestFactory;
            final int timeout = 3000;
            SSLConnectionSocketFactory socketFactory;
            try {
                socketFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(
                        SSLContext.getDefault(),
                        new String[] {"TLSv1"},
                        null,
                        SSLConnectionSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);

            Registry<ConnectionSocketFactory> socketFactoryRegistry = RegistryBuilder.<ConnectionSocketFactory>create()
                    .register("http", PlainConnectionSocketFactory.getSocketFactory())
                    .register("https", socketFactory)
                    .build();
            PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager cm = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager(socketFactoryRegistry);
            cm.setMaxTotal(700);
            cm.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(300);
            cm.closeExpiredConnections();


            RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom().setConnectTimeout(timeout)
                    .setConnectionRequestTimeout(timeout).setSocketTimeout(timeout).build();



            httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig).setConnectionManager(cm).build();


            httpRequestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);

            return httpRequestFactory;

            }

            catch (Exception e) {
                 LOGGER.debug("error exception", e);


    }
            return null; 
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a bug in your own code:

```
public BatchRestTemplate()  {
    ..........
    messageConverters.add(getBatchHTTPConverter());
    ..........

}
```

But... There is no `batchHTTPConverter` yet!. It will appear there only after `setBatchHTTPConverter()`.

In other words you can't use the property from the constructor because setters are called latter after the object instantiating.